How to identify Mixed Functions in Randomly Generated Datasets
As mentioned in this Kaggle discussion, you have 12 datasets consisting of 8,000 data points, each with 28 features. The data is generated by applying one or two different smooth functions to the data points randomly. Can current data-mining techniques identify which dataset has more than one function applied to its data points?
Sample code:
Puzzle 1
import numpy as np
import torch
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset

n_dataset = 12
numbers_of_functions = np.random.choice([1,2], (n_dataset,), p=[.5, .5])
datasets = [None]*n_dataset
mix_indices = None

for i in range(n_dataset):
    X = np.random.uniform(0, 2, size=(8000, 28)).astype(np.float32)                               # the input
    Y1 = np.sum((.5*X)**2, axis=1)-7                                                              # apply the 1st function f(x)
    Y2 = -np.sum((.5*X)**2, axis=1)+7                                                             # apply the 2nd function g(x)

    mix_indices = np.ones((len(X),),dtype=int)
    if numbers_of_functions[i] == 2:
        mix_indices = np.random.choice([0,1], (len(X),))
    Y = np.concatenate([Y1.reshape(-1,1), Y2.reshape(-1,1)], axis=-1)[range(len(X)), mix_indices] # the target
    
    datasets[i] = TensorDataset(torch.from_numpy(X), torch.from_numpy(Y))
    torch.save(datasets[i], f'./puzzle1/datasets{i}.pt')

The expected answer should be the same as the variable numbers_of_functions, i.e. the number of functions applied to each dataset.
I've never seen this type of problem before. I want to ask which category it falls into so that I can learn more about the techniques to solve it. It seems quite similar to clustering problems but appears to be more complex when it involves functions. I've tried using T-SNE and K-means but felt stuck.
